# Can we set 2 static ip in azure private endpoint with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, cloud, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-virtual-network

I want to run Aure CLI for create private endpoint on Azure databrick, It requires two ip for deploy private endpoint. I have no idea how to configure script at [--ip-config] for 2 ip. I try to search for azure document and found only case when configure 1 ip only

[image]

```
    id=$(az webapp list \
   --resource-group CreatePrivateEndpointQS-rg \
   --query '[].[id]' \
   --output tsv)

az network private-endpoint create \
   --connection-name myConnection \
   --name myPrivateEndpoint \
   --private-connection-resource-id $id \
   --resource-group CreatePrivateEndpointQS-rg \
   --subnet myBackendSubnet \
   --group-id sites \
   --ip-config name=myIPconfig group-id=sites member-name=sites private-ip-address=10.0.0.10 \
   --vnet-name myVNet
```

For my reference please follow here => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-cli?tabs=static-ip#code-try-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the below doc, Private link support for Azure Databricks is in Public Preview and:

> In the Public Preview release, only one private endpoint can be created directly from within the workspace creation flow. To create a separate front-end private endpoint from your transit VNet, you need to create an additional private endpoint but you need to do that after the workspace is deployed.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/private-link

You can use the readily available template with Azure CLI to deploy your workspace with the back-end Private link endpoint.

Refer: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/databricks-all-in-one-template-for-vnet-injection-privateendpoint/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli

The all-in-one deployment ARM template creates the following resources:

- Network security groups
- Resource groups
- VNet including subnets for the workspace (the standard two subnets) and Private Link (an additional subnet)
- Azure Databricks workspace
- The back-end Private Link endpoint

**NOTE:** The template does not create a front-end endpoint from your transit VNet. After creation of the workspace, you can add that endpoint manually.

So, there is no way to set 2 static IPs in Azure private endpoint for Azure Databricks via Azure CLI or Azure Portal since it is in Preview. You will only be able to add 1 IP and then you have to manually add the other via Portal as mentioned in below doc:

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/private-link#create-the-workspace-by-using-a-custom-template-and-optionally-add-front-end-private-endpoints